# Cannot access SimpleResponse from dialogflow webhook using Dialogflow Android Client. Cant acess Payload

Tags: android, node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, payload

Cannot access webhook payload in my android app. Therefore I am unable to show responses from the webhook into my chatbot interface in android. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [Dialogflow Android client SDK](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) to communicate between Android and Dialogflow.

Comment: I am using this library only. However the getSpeech() method only fetches the hardcoded text response from dialogflow. I want to display responses from webhook.